# CSS Grid troubles

Tags: css, less

Here is code example: http://jsfiddle.net/gubvw/3/

If you'll slowly change screen size by dragging sizer in testing window you'll see that number columns scattered.

[image: Column scattering]

What can I do to fix this trouble?

**UPDATE:** This is for FLUID CSS GRID system to make layouts for webapps. I don't want to get table. And the example is for testing this grid on resize and other dimensions.

I think that the problem is in browser which calculates .cx1 to 55+43px and round it to pixels,
and .cx5 calculates to 449+43px not watchind that .cx1 rounded to 55px.

***Specially for Dexter Huinda:***
There is 100% width? and 12 columns with 3.8% margin right (except the last).

```
So for cx1 = (1*(100+3.8))/12-3.8 = 4.85%
for cx2 = 4.85*2+3.8 = 13.5%
for cx3 = 4.85*3+3.8*2 = 22.15%
and so on.
The main formula to calculate any column width from 1 to 12 is
       (a*(100+b))/12-b (where a = number of spanned columns and b is margin)
```

Any questions to math?

And the question is why: `width(4.85%+3.8%+4.85%+3.8%+4.85%) <> width(22.15%)`

So if you need nothing to explain please find the mistake in any .cx width. Can you?

Comment: Since you have given the size in percentage that too to two decimal places.This might have caused it to go wrong. Just have a look.

Comment: Use tables instead for positioning data such as this.

Comment: All I can say is, good luck with your grid system. You need a lot of math to make this thing work.

Comment: Nothing special. And  not many math. =)

Comment: If there's nothing special, you would have solved this yourself. Try to solve it yourself, and tell us how you did it, then go back and tell me again, "nothing special".

Comment: @Dexter Huinda: You can try to take calculator and check my math. There is no mistake in math. And don't forget 3.8% right margins (except the last column)  Width for .cx5  calculates as percentage((round(((5*(100+3.8))/12-3.8)*100)/100)/100). All is very simple and clear =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13661/discussion-between-gosha-and-dexter-huinda)

Comment: @Gosha very simple indeed yet, you can't solve it, that's how simple this thing is.

Comment: @Dexter Huinda: Please, go to the chat, and I'll explain you

Comment: @GOsha what is there to explain? This is so simple [like you said, no-brainer].

Comment: @Dexter Huinda: Added special part for you in my question. Enjoy =)

Comment: @Gosha right, very easy to comprehend, even a first-grader can read them. So simple, yet could never find the solution.

Comment: I think your assumption that all the divs widths, which add up to 100% , should display at the same pixel widths, is wrong. The widths are approximated by the browser. Before rushing off to go invent your own grid system you should do some research into browser rendering.

Comment: Solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NwkPz/.
Thanx to Vasiliy Aksenov (Web Standards Days) && Vadim Makeev (Opera Software)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NwkPz/.
Thanx to Vasiliy Aksyonov (Web Standards Days) && Vadim Makeev (Opera Software)
[image: yeah]

))

Answer (score 0):

Either you should use div with fixed width that you may provide in your css file or you can make it via table. Actually your divs are not properly tightened together. This is the main reason.

Comment: I don't want to use fixed width divs. I want to make fluid css grid system to use it in other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach could do with some rethinking.

If you need to align columns, use either a table or use fixed width divs. You are using classes, so why not apply fixed widths via the class, and not the percentage widths that are there.

Using a fixed width font in conjunction could also give a desired effect.

Comment: No, I don't want to do a table with divs. I want to make fluid css grid system to use it in other apps.

Comment: My options were a table or fixed width divs. I didnt suggest to use both together.

Comment: @GOsha Tables are also fluid, just use percentages to enforce the fluidity. Tables are designed for presentation of data, like the one in your example.

Comment: I want to get my own modern grid CSS framework like Blueprint or cssgrid.net. I don`t want to use fixed table layout on my pages.